# Booking system - WP

Tags: wordpress

I need to do a reservation for 3 restaurants- in each there are 12 tables. Some of the reservations have to be paid before, the rest of them not at all.

Also, there is a need to identify if in the particular restaurant there is a reservation for different events- then the functionality of not-paid reservation must be switch off.

Ideally, if mails with reservations should be delivered to various email addresses - based on the name of the restaurant.

Everything must run on WP.

Can you please assist me with that?

Answer (score 0):

For this system, I suggest you this solution.
**I should say that using this answer requires average knowledge of PHP and WordPress functions.**

1. Create a custom post type for Restaurants.
2. Information such as not-paid reservation, paid reservation, and events can be saved as meta values.
3. To save meta values for your custom post type, you can use the "advanced custom fields" plugin or just code them using `add_meta_box()`.
4. For the reservations, you should make a form and in the form, users can select their reservation table, date, and time.
5. if the reservation requires payment, you should check the gateway documentation and use their script.
   here you need to create a table in the database for payments.
   **after the form submits and before payment, add your user info to the database and give the payment status "pending" value.**
6. after the successful or unsuccessful payment, the gateway will return the payment status and with that, you can save the reservation status.
7. For sending an email to the restaurant manager, after the successful payment, use `wp_mail()`.

I tried to explain the whole project to you in 12 lines so, after reading this answer you may get confused.
If you have more questions, just ask.